# URL other than base('/') is crashing on server and working fine in localhost using $routeprovider in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am working on angularjs project. Whenever I run my application on my local and refresh the page with url (ex. localhost:9000/online-order) other than base (ex. localhost:9000/), it is redirecting to home page ('/') but when i run my application on server and refresh the page with url (ex. order.posist.co/online-order) other than base (ex. order.posist.co), page crashes and giving 404 error.

for your reference you can check on http://order.posist.co

Comment: Can you post the code please.

Answer (score 0):

try with order.posist.co:9000/#/online-order

AngularJS is a single page app so you need "#" in your route how a redirect into the same page; other possibility is problem in the port or in the server, what server are your using?

if you are using grunt you need the command `grunt build` to generate the deploy folder